# meta.mathoverflow.net links are not handled by SE App for Android

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, hyperlinks

If you tap a link to a post on [Meta MathOverflow](http://meta.mathoverflow.net) **from mobile browser**, Android doesn't provide a choice to open it on SE app, and instead just open the post in the browser.

This bug also made tapping the "Read this post in our app!" link on the top failed, redirecting to Play Store (even though the app is already installed) instead of opening the post directly on the app.

As can be seen, these are the links that SE app (as of v1.0.73) supports:

[image: supported links 1] [image: supported links 2]

<sup>Click the image to see the full version</sup>

> - *.stackexchange.com
> - stackoverflow.com
> - meta.stackoverflow.com
> - pt.stackoverflow.com
> - ja.stackoverflow.com
> - ru.stackoverflow.com
> - superuser.com
> - meta.superuser.com
> - serverfault.com
> - meta.serverfault.com
> - askubuntu.com
> - meta.askubuntu.com
> - mathoverflow.net (no meta.mathoverflow.net)
> - stackapps.com
>
> <sup>The list is sorted for convenience</sup>

---

Example (**open this link from Android mobile browser, not from SE app**: click "More" on this question, and select "Open in browser" first):

- [Happy 5th anniversary, MathOverflow!](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1915/happy-5th-anniversary-mathoverflow) on Meta MathOverflow
- [Examples of common false beliefs in mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics) on MathOverflow main site

Spec: Nexus 5 on Marshmallow 6.0, SE app v1.0.73

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you mean the Stack Exchange app for android, or a browser (e.g. Chrome) running on android. You say app, then on other sentence you say browser. The SE app **is not a browser**.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The post is about the app handling links in mobile browser, and is perfectly clear to me.

Comment: @19 well, not to me, hopefully the devs will understand.

Comment: Finally clear now, after the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

We actually meant to support meta.mathoverflow.net. We just had mathoverflow.net listed twice in the manifest instead.